# SharePoint via Web Service: Get Details of a List Item

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am able to get the items from a list view using Lists.GetListItems() function. How can I get the details of each individual item?

E.g. From GetListItems() function, I can only retrieve "LinkTitle" and "Title" of a item, but I can't get the detail information of the item, e.g. author, detailed info etc.

Anyone can help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the fields you want to get in `ViewFields` parameter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442073(v=office.12).aspx

```
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
  <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"></FieldRef>
  <FieldRef Name="Status"></FieldRef>
  <FieldRef Name="Priority"></FieldRef>
  <FieldRef Name="DueDate"></FieldRef>
  <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>
```